# Dynamization of UTM parameters at product level

Tags: marketing-cloud

What is the best way to dynamize UTM parameters at link level? In the Web Analytics Connector I use Additional Email Attributes and personalization strings, e.g. `utm_campaign=%%emailname_%%%`.

I tried to use `%%linkname%%%` as `utm_content`, which doesn't work.

What can I do instead if I want to use either the name of the content block or the name of the product or product category as UTM content dynamically. Using the link alias would basically be perfect.